# The method func(List<Object>) in the type is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have tried both these pieces of code but I am getting errors for both.
Attached below are both pieces and both errors that I am getting.
I would appreciate any insight as to why this is happening.

Example 1

```
static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {    
  func(list);    
}

private static void func(List<Object> lst) {                
}
```

Error:

> `The method func(List<Object>) in the type is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)`

Example 2

```
static List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    func(list);    
}

private static void func(List<String> lst) {
}
```

Error:

> `The method func(List<String>) in the type is not applicable for the arguments (List<Object>)`

Comment: Generics are not covariant! That is, `List<Object>` cannot be substituted with `List<String>` or the other way around!

Comment: You can't make the second one functional with the same semantics. The first one should work if you declare your func as ```private static void func(List<?> lst)```

Answer (score 8):

The method is not applicable because `String` is an `Object` but `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 2):

Why you can't pass a `List<String>` to a `List<Object>`:

```
void bong(List<Object> objs) {
    objs.add ( new Integer(42) );
}
List<String> strings = Arrays.toList("foo", bar");
bong(strings);    // not allowed because ... see next line
for (String s : strings) print(x.charAt(0));
```

This would be safe only if the method couldn't modify the passed list. Unfortunatly, most Java classes are mutable, and so are most Lists implementations.

Why you can't pass a `List<Object>` to a `List<String>`:

```
void bing(List<String> strings) {
    for (String s : strings) print(x.charAt(0));
}
bing(Arrays.toList((Object)1,(Object)2,(Object)3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    func(list);

}

private static void func(List<Object> lst) {

}
```

This should work **with the right imports** (java util).

You can't supply `List<Object>` to a method with the parameter `List<String>`. It will only work with the same type parameters.

Comment: My question is why?
String is an subtype of object so it should work...

Comment: Check @Heuster's comment on your question.

Comment: @ronreish Because it is not typesafe.

Answer (score 0):

You should basically understand the purpose of Generics and how it works:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

means that this list can only contain list of strings, and it can only be passed to methods that accepts the argument of type `List<String>`. And you can not substitute it for `List <Object>`.

In order to make the function more generic you can use:

```
function (List<?> list) {
    //body
}
```