# Generics : add `List<String>` to `List<Object>`

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am not good at Generics but can someone let me know how am I able to add `List<String>` to `List<Object>` in the below code?
Or, am I missing out something very fundamental.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20356096/5086633

> The method is not applicable because `String` is an `Object` but
>   `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`.

```
     public static void main(String args[]) {

                List<Object>  testObj = new LinkedList<Object>();
                List<String>  testString = new LinkedList<String>();
                testObj.add("TestObjValue1");
                testObj.add("TestObjValue2");
            testObj.add("TestObjValue3");
            testObj.add("TestObjValue4");
            testString.add("TestStrValue1");
            testString.add("TestStrValue2");
            testString.add("TestStrValue3");
            testString.add("TestStrValue4");

            System.out.println(testObj);

    testObj.addAll(testString);

    System.out.println(testObj);

//testString.add(testObj);  --> Compile time Error

//testObj stores reference of type Object
//testString stores reference of type String
//so a String type List reference can store String type alone
//However Object type List ref variable can store Object and its subclasses??
```

**Output**

```
[TestObjValue1, TestObjValue2, TestObjValue3, TestObjValue4, 
[TestStrValue1, TestStrValue2, TestStrValue3, TestStrValue4]]


[TestObjValue1, TestObjValue2, TestObjValue3, TestObjValue4,
[TestStrValue1, TestStrValue2, TestStrValue3, TestStrValue4],
TestStrValue1, TestStrValue2, TestStrValue3, TestStrValue4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add an actual `List` to the `List` that may only contain `String`s, to successfully add each individual item, you will need to loop through the `testObj` list and add them individually

```
for (Object obj : testObj) {
    testString.add(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```